# How can I find the impact factor of a publication in IEEE library?

Tags: computer-science, computer-science-theory

I am new in computer science research. I am working on a research project and my question is how can I detect the impact factor of a publication in IEEE? Does IEEE provide this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is better suited for https://academia.stackexchange.com/.

But to answer your question, you can see top journals by impact factor here: http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/journmag/journalcitations.html#sect2.

Comment: Ok, i did not have in mind the existence of academia.stackexchange.com. I will try there, thank you.

Comment: @anvlasop: No worries. Good luck with your research!